# To prove $\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{b} + \dfrac{1}{c} \leq 3 + \dfrac{2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)}{abc}$ when a + b + c = 1, a >0, b>0, c>0 and positive real.

Tags: inequality

Let a, b, c > 0 be real positive numbers with a + b + c = 1. Prove:

$\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{b} + \dfrac{1}{c} \leq 3 + \dfrac{2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)}{abc}$

I tried AM-HM on the lhs but I'm absolutely stumped. I think this might involve nesbitts inequality but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Autopilot mode: Just homogenise and use Muirhead's.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the LHS using $a+b+c=1$ as
$$
\sum_{cyc}1/a= 3+\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{a},
$$
So the target inequality is
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{a}\leq 2\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}.
$$
Homogenizing:
$$
\sum_{cyc}b^2c+c^2b\leq2(a^3+b^3+c^3),
$$
Apply AM-GM:
$$
\sum_{cyc}b^2c+c^2b \leq \sum_{cyc}b^3+c^3=2(a^3+b^3+c^3).
$$
Done.